# Does the Android Maps Api have any quotas?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm currently looking into creating an android app that needs a map. Since everyone knows google maps, i thought why not to use it? I need "only" the map, with some markers and so on, but no (reverse-)geocoding or other special stuff.

At https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload it doesn't list android "stuff" as a mapload. At the android pages i can't find anything to that topic, but it doesn't seem very intuitiv that on the one hand you have to pay for the javascript version (if you have more than 25k views per day) and on the other hand the android version is for free.

A short google / stackoverflow search delivered alot of different results. Some threads/topics/??? say that you have to for android views as like as for javascript views and others say that android maps are for free...

Is the usage of the google maps android api for free or does it have a free quota as like as the javascript api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the link you mentioned (https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload), the "native Maps APIs for mobile platforms such as Android" is not affected by usage limits.

So, yes, it is for free and does not have a usage limit!

Comment: This affirmative was removed from the docs. Does it mean now it is not free anymore?